# What are the criteria to decide revascularization vs apexification in a young permanent tooth with necrosed pulp?

Tags: dentistry, pediatrics

If a paediatric patient comes to the clinic with necrosed pulp either due to trauma or caries in one of his/her young permanent tooth then should apexification be done or revascularization? What are the criteria to decide among these two procedures? Since both these procedures have similar indications and contraindications.
[Reference](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-19476-9_9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from my professor, though it's nowhere given on the net.

Apexification is done in cases where there is **2-2/3rd root canal length** is remaining and the root canal apex is **convergent**.

> The objective of this procedure is to induce root end closure (apexification) at the apices of immature roots through the formation of mineralized tissue.

[Reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apexification#:%7E:text=4%20Follow%20up-,Indication%20and%20objectives,the%20formation%20of%20mineralized%20tissue.)

Regeneration procedure is done in cases where the root canal apex is **blunderbuss** or **parallel** and the canal length is **less than half** and hence less dentinal wall left.

> Immature teeth with a large open apex and short roots seem to be more conducive to the successful treatment of pulp revascularization.

[Reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4212590/#:%7E:text=Immature%20teeth%20with%20a%20large,successful%20treatment%20of%20pulp%20revascularization.&text=This%20pulp%20revascularization%20is%20used,cells%20are%20able%20to%20survive.)

[image]

[Reference](https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1677-32252013000100013)

In the left tooth the root canal apex is convergent with open apex whereas in the right tooth the open canal apex is divergent or blunderbuss.